# how to work with Checkbox in Custom Adapter

Tags: android, checkbox

I am working with checkbox which is in my custom Adapter.I used the Interface in Activity to send that checkbox text in another listview the problem i am facing that when i add the item to checkbox and checked the checkbox the application get stop working..but when i reopen the app and try to checked its again its workfine.when i try to add one new item to checkbox same issue happen and vice-versa

Logcat error:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.advoco.notepad.ListAdapter$onItemChecked.onItemClick(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.advoco.notepad.ListAdapter$1.onCheckedChanged(ListAdapter.java:51)
                                                                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:156)
                                                                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:115)
                                                                  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:120)
                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)


public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<NoteDone> {
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
List<NoteDone> noteDones;
private onItemChecked onClick;
public ListAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<NoteDone> noteDones) {
    super(context, resource,noteDones);
    this.context = context;
    this.noteDones = noteDones;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView notDone;
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
public interface onItemChecked{
    void onItemClick(int position);
}
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ListAdapter.ViewHolder holder;
    final NoteDone model = noteDones.get(position);
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ListAdapter.ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notdone, null);
        holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ListAdapter.ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.checkBox.setText(model.getTask());
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            onClick.onItemClick(position);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
public void setOnClick(onItemChecked onClick)
{
    this.onClick=onClick;
}
}
```

My activity class:

```
public class ToDo extends AppCompatActivity implements 
ListAdapter.onItemChecked{
DBhelper dBhelper;
ListView lstTask,listView;
List<NoteDone> taskList,tasklist2;
ListAdapter listAdapter;
ListAdapter2 listAdapter2;
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.todo);
    lstTask = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.nd);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.done);
    LoadTask();
    LoadTask2();
    listAdapter.setOnClick(this);
   /*lstTask.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = taskList.get(position).getTask();
            dBhelper.insertNewTask2(name);
            dBhelper.deleteTask(name);
            LoadTask();
            LoadTask2();
        }
    });*/
}
public void LoadTask() {
    dBhelper = new DBhelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    taskList = dBhelper.getTaskList(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (taskList != null) {
        listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.notdone, taskList);
        lstTask.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
}
public void LoadTask2() {
    dBhelper = new DBhelper(getApplicationContext());
    sqLiteDatabase = dBhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    tasklist2 = dBhelper.getTaskList2(sqLiteDatabase);
    if (tasklist2 != null) {
        listAdapter2 = new ListAdapter2(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.done, tasklist2);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter2);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.todo_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.action_add_task:
            final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Add New Task")
                    .setMessage("What do you want to do next?")
                    .setView(taskEditText)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEditText.getText());
                            dBhelper.insertNewTask(task);
                            LoadTask();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",null)
                    .create();
            dialog.show();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {
    String name = taskList.get(position).getTask();
    dBhelper.insertNewTask2(name);
    dBhelper.deleteTask(name);
    LoadTask();
    LoadTask2();
}
}
```

Comment: Show your Activity class

Comment: Updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listAdapter.setOnClick(this);
```

this line should be included on LoadTask() method after setting the adapter. remove 
listAdapter.setOnClick(this); from onCreate(). Add this on LoadTask().

```
lstTask.setAdapter(listAdapter);
listAdapter.setOnClick(this);
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Happy that it works perfectly & u accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with your inflaming view. change following

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.notdone, null);
```

To

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.notdone, parent, false);
```

Hope this will resolve the issue